# Vue-router does not show component on page

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I have problem with my router. I want show **bodyComponent** on my index page, but nothing happen.
I use laravel+vue. Where I can make mistake? I not got mistake

My router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import bodyComponent from '../views/bodyComponent'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router= new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes:[
        {
            path:"/",
            components: {
                default: bodyComponent,
            }
        }
    ]
})
export default router;
```

app.js

```
import router from "./router"
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

My index.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
        <header-component></header-component> 
        <!--<body-component></body-component>-->
        <router-view></router-view>
        <footer-component></footer-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Try defining a name for your `router-view`.
`<router-view name="default"></router-view>`

Answer (score 0):

I change path in my vue route and components show on index page. On application index page I come from laravel router. So I change path to index page in vue router on name same in laravel route

My laravel router

```
Route::get('/tobyten', function () {
        return view('tobyten.index');
    })->name('tobyten');
```

My vue router

```
const router= new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes:[
        {
            path:"/tobyten",
            components: {
                default: bodyComponent,
            }
        }
    ]
})
```